# What is the CefSharp alternative of Cef3 CefURLRequest function

Tags: cefsharp

I am trying to implement CefURLRequest function outside the CefSharp browser instance for making additional API requests to fetch dependent data.

I searched everywhere for CefURLRequest implementation of CefSharp but I could not find it. I need to know if CefSharp has it available in its current version.

Comment: The `CefURLRequest` class maps to [UrlRequest](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/113.1.x/html/T_CefSharp_UrlRequest.htm).

Comment: Thank you. Can you share an example link?

Comment: There is an example in the unit tests https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.Test